# how to create onClick event in server side node JS simply?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webserver

I just wanted this for test.

For example, here is server code in node JS.

As i mentioned below, i want to make onclick event properly and simply.

Because it is just for test for client side.

How to solve it? is that wrong way to use like this??

```
 http.createServer((request, response) => {
  return request
  .on('error', (err) => { 
    console.error(err);
  })
  .on('data', (data) => { 
      //data exists

    }).
  on('end',()=>{
    response.statusCode = 200; 
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    response.write('<html>'); 

    response.write('<h1> List</h1>'); 
    response.write('<button onclick="sendToServer(data)">submit</button>'); <--this line
    //I want to make onclick event for above 
    //but it excutes even user didnt click the button
    response.write('</html>'); 
   });
}).listen(3030);


function  sendToServer(data){
   request.post({
        headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                  'Content-Type': "application/json"
                  },
            url:'https://...',
            body:JSON.stringify(data)
            }, function(e, r, body){
              console.log(body);
      });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need implement http route for listen client side request on server side
2. Make function for send request to server on client side (I've used simple jquery ajax get method)

and final working code is here

```js
var http = require('http');
var HttpDispatcher = require('httpdispatcher');;
var dispatcher = new HttpDispatcher();

http.createServer((request, response) => {
    return request
    .on('error', (err) => { 
      console.error(err);
    })
    .on('data', (data) => { 
        //data exists
    }).
    on('end',()=>{
      dispatcher.dispatch(request, response);
    });
  }).listen(3030);

  dispatcher.onGet("/", function(request, response) {
    response.statusCode = 200; 
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/html'});
    response.write('<html>'); 
    response.write('<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>');
    response.write('<script>function sendToServer(){$.ajax("/route").done(function(data){alert( data );});}</script>');
    response.write('<h1> List</h1>'); 
    response.write('<button onclick="sendToServer()">submit</button>');
    response.write('</html>');
    response.end();
  });

  dispatcher.onGet("/route", function(request, response) {
    response.end("Server responding!!!"); //call your any serverside function here
  });
```